# I want to prevent HTML elements from moving each other and let them overlap

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, position

I have a series of drop downs that are hidden and enable when needed (they are each different and when you chose a choice in a different drop down, the desired on is set to visible). Problem is, they are all over so if I select something at the end of the previous drop down, my desired drop down appears far away (because the hidden element's padding keep it over there). How can i prevent things from being moved around in HTML. Do I need to use CSS? Thanks!

Comment: _"I have a"_ please post a [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 0):

You will need CSS.

I also recommend using JavaScript if you are familiar with it; CSS will help with it's pseudo selectors and you will have more control over the DOM with JS.

Comment: I would also look into CSS layout tools like Grid, flexbox, and the standard display property